# Open Layers Hover event not working

Tags: openlayers

I can't get the hover event to register properly, I don't know why.  I have done some so far unfruitful we research, any ideas???  The first line works great, but the second does not.

Thanks

ClientOverlay.events.register("click", ClientOverlay, markerClick);

ClientOverlay.events.register("hover", ClientOverlay, markerClick);

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's the way to use the hover event, I have only used hovering with the Handler object:

http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Handler/Hover-js.html